# Django: Change status and color in a bootstrap button

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the status (from Authenticate to Authenticated) and color (from default to success) on a bootstrap button whenever my Soundcloud API has authenticated its user and is redirected back to my website.

Here is my Soundcloud class in `views.py`:

```
class SoundcloudAccountView(PodcastRequiredMixin, View):
    form_class = SoundcloudAccountForm
    template_name = 'pod_funnel/forms_soundcloud_account.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # We check if we have a Soundcloud config for this users podcast, if not
        # redirect directly to Oauth 2, otherwise show form
        soundcloud_config_id = self.podcast.soundcloud_account_id
        if soundcloud_config_id is None:
            soundcloud_config = SoundcloudConfig(client=self.client)
            soundcloud_config.save()
            self.podcast.soundcloud_account = soundcloud_config
            self.podcast.save()
        else:
            soundcloud_config = self.podcast.soundcloud_account

        if not soundcloud_config.is_authenticated():
            client_id = settings.PODFUNNEL_SOUNDCLOUD_APP_CLIENT_ID
            client_secret = settings.PODFUNNEL_SOUNDCLOUD_APP_CLIENT_SECRET
            redirect_uri = settings.PODFUNNEL_SOUNDCLOUD_APP_AUTH_CALLBACK
            api = SoundcloudAPI(soundcloud_config, request, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri)
            request_url_response = api.get_authentication_url()

            if request_url_response.success and request_url_response.redirect_url:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request_url_response.redirect_url)

        initial_values = {'name': soundcloud_config.screen_name}
        form = self.form_class(initial=initial_values)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    # if we get a post request on this view, it means the user wants to reauthenticate or delete.
    # Delete current soundcloud config and call get for reauthenticate otherwise back to accounts.
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        soundcloud_config_id = self.podcast.soundcloud_account_id
        if soundcloud_config_id is not None:
            SoundcloudConfig.objects.filter(id=soundcloud_config_id).delete()

        isDelete = request.POST.get('action', None) == 'Delete'
        if isDelete:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('podfunnel:accounts'))
        return self.get(request, args, kwargs)


class SoundcloudAuthenticationView(LoginRequiredMixin, RedirectView):
    pattern_name = 'podfunnel:soundcloudaccount'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        soundcloud_config_id = self.request.session.get('soundcloud_config_id')
        self.request.session.delete('soundcloud_config_id')
        soundcloud_config = get_object_or_404(SoundcloudConfig, id=soundcloud_config_id)

        # Now we need to exchange the tokens
        client_id = settings.PODFUNNEL_SOUNDCLOUD_APP_CLIENT_ID
        client_secret = settings.PODFUNNEL_SOUNDCLOUD_APP_CLIENT_SECRET
        redirect_uri = settings.PODFUNNEL_SOUNDCLOUD_APP_AUTH_CALLBACK
        api = SoundcloudAPI(soundcloud_config, request, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri)
        exchangeTokenResponse = api.get_tokens_for_authentication_callback(self.request)

        # If succesfull update 'soundcloud_config' info
        # Otherwise we redirect without saving.
        if exchangeTokenResponse.success:
            soundcloud_config.access_token = exchangeTokenResponse.access_token
            response = api.me() # Get name

            if response.success:
                soundcloud_config.screen_name = response.resource.get('username')
                soundcloud_config.save()

        return super(SoundcloudAuthenticationView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And here is the code in the template where I want the button to change its color and status whenever the user is redirected successfully from Soundcloud:

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <br>
            <a class="btn btn-warning box-shadow--6dp" href="{% url 'podfunnel:soundcloudaccount' %}" role="button">Authenticate</a>
            <br>
        </div>
```

Any suggestion on how I can implement this? Could I do this without implementing `jQuery`?

Would appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can render bootstrap status to your template, like

```
return render(request, self.template_name, {'status': 'btn btn-success'})
return render(request, self.template_name, {'status': 'btn btn-danger'})
```

then use it in the template, like

```
<input type="button" class={{status}} value="" />
```